# jQuery load() taking a long time

Tags: jquery, html

Sometimes my jquery call to load a page takes a long time (about 30+ seconds) and sometimes it loads quickly like it's supposed to. I tried recreating the problem in jsfiddle since the actual page has a lot of code. However, I can't get it to work at all in jsfiddle. Here's the link to the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VtTXv/

Here's the code:

```
<span id="html_currentthread" style="background-color:blue;" hidden>f</span>
<span class="Row_0">fdas<span>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    center_currentthread3 = $(window).width() / 2;    
    $(".Row_0").on('click', function () {
                            $('#html_currentthread').animate({height: '600px', width: '600px', left: center_currentthread3+'px', opacity: '1'},700).css('z-index','60');
                                $('#html_currentthread').show();
                                $('#html_currentthread').load('http://www.google.com');

                            });
});
    </script>
```

Update:
I have confirmed that the page loads quickly when I have let the page be idle and not on any other loaded page in that menu (ie on the page without anything selected). If I try to load another and a few minutes have not gone by (it might be somewhere around 1-2 minutes, up to 3), it takes a long time to load (around 30+ seconds usually). I'm now thinking this is a server issue and not a code issue. It's a WAMP server (running an Apache server). It's like a backwards idle, where it works after a certain amount of time being idle with none of the pages on the menu open.

Comment: Maybe the server is slow?

Comment: It's on my computer and the page that I'm loading loads super quickly if I load it directly.

Comment: What do you mean you can't get it to work? As in you can't reproduce it, or you can't get jsfiddle to work with your code?

Comment: The jsfiddle didn't load anything at all.

Comment: Then how is it of use in solving this problem? Do you want us to fix the fiddle, or fix your PC?

Comment: Are you saying it's my PC? The code is similar to that in the page. I figure the reason this jsfiddle isn't working might have something to do with the problem at hand.

Answer (score 2):

When I switch to JQuery 1.9, I get this message in your fiddle:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.google.nl/. Origin
>   http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

For some reason JQuery 1.10 doesn't generate this message, but the problem I think is the same: You've run into a (the) [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) which doesn't allow you to do AJAX requests to other domains.

At least, this is the problem in your fiddle. It doesn't explain why you *do* get results on your local machine. There, you probably did use the same local machine in the AJAX request as well. In that case you're not bothered by the policy.

The reason of slowing down? Who can tell. Maybe...

- the server requests takes a long time (slow PHP script)
- you got other processes running that take up CPU power
- your web server kills idle worker processes, having to start them again when you do your requests
- Chrome will only execute two requests to the same server at once and will queue others, making them *seem* slower
- ...

Comment: you can make ajax call to other domains, it's up to them to decide.

Comment: @sUP your browser prevents it, although I think FireFox permits the requests, but doesn't return the response. Anyway, you cannot read the response into your element. There are exceptions, like using JSONP, but these are also summed up in the page I linked to.

Comment: Could you explain the server killing idle worker processes? Would this cause a randomized 0-40 second delay in loading a page?

Comment: I don't know if that goes for every web server, but I know IIS has worker processes (w3wp.exe) that are killed by default after 20 minutes. That means that if you don't do requests in that time, the process has to be restarted upon the first request after that period. This is very quick normally, but if you load a more heavy application, it might take longer to startup. I've had 'random' requests slow down by more than a minute, because I had an ISAPI dll that took over a minute to initialize. Not completely random, of course, only after a noticable long idle time.

Comment: This happens immediately. Thanks for pointing out the thing about the idle time. I'll have to check that on my page as it's not something I normally would've checked. Other `.load()` requests work fine, just this one works differently. There's nothing really different about it that I can tell. I suspect it might have something to do with the server, but I don't think it's a timeout.

Comment: Maybe you should do some testing using other urls that are know to work well. Also, logging on the server might help. If you log your requests on the server, you might notice delays in those logs when you do the requests. If you can't find it, maybe you can post a new question, but make sure to include your server configuration and the script that is delaying.

Comment: With the site itself, the URL is to a page in the same directory, so that's not the issue really. It loads, but it takes a really long time. However, while testing, I just discovered that it seems (I'm still testing it) that if I wait a while and click a link (there are a several), the page loads immediately, however when I click another link soon afterwards, it doesn't load quickly and I have to wait a couple minutes before opening another page. It doesn't load quickly when close to page load, either, just after a while of doing nothing.

Comment: I'd like to update to say so far it's confirmed that in order for the page to load quickly, i must have it on the main screen (not a menu) for a few minutes. Then, when I click the link that opens the page, it loads immediately.